# How to refactor Python code dependant on fork() copying state

Tags: python, multiprocessing, fork, state

I'm working on a large-ish Python code base that's been around for over a decade now. The application in question makes use of forking for it's parallelism.

The basic premise is that the user asks the program to build a particular target, we figure out a dependancy graph for the target, then from topological partitions in the build graph figure out some tasks we can perform in parallel. We then fork some processes to perform those tasks (from the partition) in parallel.

It all kind of works. However I'd like to refactor it NOT to depend on `fork()`. In particular, it's the *dependancy on state from the master process being available in the child processes* that's a problem.

There are a couple of motivating factors for the refactoring:

1. I'd like to have the code as similar as possible between Linux
   and Windows (currently on Windows we perform a non forking build,
   thus no parallelism)
2. The forking is a little ugly with respect to
   other refactoring I want to do (basically, I'd like to have more
   centralised control and monitoring of building). Instead of forking,
   I'd like to go through the Python Multiprocessing module (which I've
   used in the past with good results).

The problem is quite a lot of data structures that are currently used by the forked processes (which were set up by the master process) cannot easily be serialized (nor can they be inferred for construction by the child process). Open file descriptors is one such example, dependancy on object identity (build graph) is another.

Basically, I'm looking for advice on how to best approach this problem holistically.

Comment: @AlexShkop multiprocessing module is ultimately where I want to end up. However the real problem is addressing the dependancy on state being copied with forking. Note that on Linux multiprocessing spawns new processes with fork (state copied) while on Windows (which does not have fork) it does not.

Comment: I'm not sure why you have to reuse pointers to file descriptors. Sounds like a bad idea. Anyway you have to distinguish between data and helpers, accessors, etc. FD is not data. You can put all of your data into a shared place (for example sqlite?). Now you can simply run independent processes working on the same shared structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I propose following paradigm

**Master** is a single process and does all the dependency resolution, graph partitioning, etc, down to single, individual job. Thus there is only one copy of system state.

These leaf jobs are offloaded using `subprocess` or `multiprocessing` or `os.system`.

The simpler offload mechanism, the more platform independence :)

**Leaves** are of course asynchronous, thus you need a framework for handling asynchronous notifications -- you can use `gevent` or some library that implements `futures`. If you are truly hardcore, `twisted`. Python 3.x also brings in `asyncio` that may be useful.

You can also use a resource / executor pool with ad-hoc notifications, e.g. [post-order tranversal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pre-order_traversal#Post-order_2) which I think can be implemented relatively simply using a recursive function, or in your case, recursive generator.

Comment: That's basically what the current code does anyway (full dependency resolution in the master process, atomic targets to be built are sent to child processes). The _problem_ is that the targets to be built (as determined by dependency resolution) are a) complex objects with a lot of state that cannot currently be serialized (including file descriptors) and b) going to be difficult to get into a state where they _can_ be serialized (due to the nature of our codebase).

Comment: As long as you don't perform heavy computation in Python in these "leaves", perhaps you can break them down to series of `os.system` or `subprocess.Popen` calls? In that case you can totally use `threading` or if total number of external ops is too large, `gevent`. Point is to move target logic into the main process.

Comment: I think the answer to my real question is that "If you can't nicely describe a build task without forking, then the code needs refactoring". There's no magic bullet that provides fork like functionality in a platform agnostic way. Marking this answer as accepted as it's the closest to "correct".

Comment: a bit OT: the closest to `fork` within a process is `cPickle.loads(cPickle.dumps(obj))`. It's even better than `copy.deepcopy()`. it may take a lot of work to make custom classes and resources picklable/findable though, YMMV.